# Github dependabot v2 update on push

Tags: github, dependabot

So I'm using github dependabot v2 and have this config:

```yml
version: 2
updates:
  - package-ecosystem: npm
    directory: "/"
    schedule:
      interval: daily
    open-pull-requests-limit: 100
    allow:
      - dependency-type: all
```

I want it to check for updates whenever I make a push / change.
How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this with dependabot and likely they will never implement it. It is supposed to run separated on schedule as it is itself likely to produce a PR.

Also there no (practical) way to run it locally, especially after github bought them.

Answer (score 0):

dependabot its separate application, thus it has its own lifecycle. It has its own metadata store and runs against it for creating PRs daily, weekly, and monthly.

It used to have live checks, I saw that checking interval got removed in v2.